# Calculate the range of the function $f(x)=-x^2+6x$ with the domain $[2,5]$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Consider the function $f(x)=-x^2+6x$ with the domain $[2,5]$. Now calculate the range of the function according to its domain.

Here is my solution:

The domain is $2\leq x\leq5$ so I can wrote:

1. $2\leq x\leq5\implies4\leq x^2\leq25\implies-4\geq-x^2\geq-25\implies\boxed{-25\leq-x^2\leq-4}\ (\text{1})$
2. $2\leq x\leq5\implies\boxed{12\leq6x\leq30}\ (\text{2})$

Then I calculated the sum of the two inequalities $(\text{1})$ and $(\text{2})$. So the range is $-13\leq-x^2+6x\leq26$. But since this was a question from a calculus book, I know that the correct answer is $[5,9]$ and not $[-13,26]$. So what is the problem of my solution?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It's true that $-13\le -x^2+6x \le 26$, but not all that interval is in the range, because (1) and (2) are not independent:  e.g., when $x=5$, then $-x^2=-25$ and $6x=30$

Comment: Let's pick on the point $26$ in your interval. How could $f$ possibly attain this value, according to your argument? $26$ is what happens when both $-x^2$ and $6x$ achieve their maximum possible values, individually. But, you'll note, that they never achieve their maxima at the same time! To get $26$, we need to sub $x = 2$ into $-x^2$, and at the same time, $x = 5$ into $6x$. But, we can't do both at the same time when calculating $f(x)$. So, $26$ (among others) will not be in the range, despite your computations. You've shown the range is contained in $[-13,26]$.

Comment: Since you can use calculus, note that $f$ is continuous, find its critical points, then evaluate $f$ at them and the endpoints.

Comment: You can have $6x$ be as low as $12$ (when $x=2$) and you can have $-x^2$ be as low as $-25$ (when $x=5$) but you can't have $6x$ be as low as $12$ and $-x^2$ be as low as $-25$ **at the same time**.  When $6x$ is $12$ then $-x^2$ is *NOT* $-25$ and $-13$ is never a possible value.  And so on.

Comment: On the other hand.  $-x^2 + 6x$ is continuous and if $x = 2$ then $-x^2 + 6x = 8$ and if $x=5$ then $-x^2+6x= 5$ so we know that all the values between $5$ and $8$ must be in the domain so $[5,8]\subset DOMAIN$.  It'd me a mistake to assume that $[5,8]$ *is* the domain because although it begins at $8$ and ends at $5$ it might get higher than $8$ and/or lower than $5$ in between.  .... you need a method of finding the maximum and or minimum it can achieve in between.  Basically we have $[5,8]\subseteq DOMAIN =[min, max] \subsetneq [-13,26]$. Just need to find min and max.

Comment: @fleablood:  did you mean $RANGE$ where you typed $DOMAIN$?

Comment: The answers posted so far address the title correctly, but, unlike the comments, they don't answer the question, "What is the problem of my solution?"

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Of course, I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative $f'(x)=-2x+6$ has one zero at $x=3$. The maximum and minimum values will occur either at the endpoints of the domain or at $x=3$. Simply plug these $x$ values into $f$ to check.

$f(2)=-(2)^2+6(2)=8$

$f(3)=-(3)^2+6(3)=9$

$f(5)=-(5)^2+6(5)=5$

This gives us a minimum value of $5$ and a maximum value of $9$. So the range is $[5,9]$ as you said.

Comment: Thanks to Weierstrass' theorem, since $f$ is continuous on a closed and bounded interval.

Comment: This is an algebra pre calculus question, are there derivatives in pre calculus?

Comment: @Thatπthere The question states that the problem is from a calculus textbook.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of geometry:

$y=-x^2 +6x$ with $x\in [2,5];$

$y=-(x^2-6x)=-(x-3)^2+9$;

This is a parabola opening downward with maximum  at $x=3$: $y_{max} =9;$

$y_{min} =-(5-3)^2+9=5$, and we are done.
(Why is $x=5$ chosen for the minimum?)